# What is the best way to implement update counter in Ecto/Phoenix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In ruby on rails(active record) we can update the counter just by calling 
    `update_counter` method. for example in rails you just need to write:

```
  # For the Post with id of 5, decrement the comment_count by 1, and
  # increment the action_count by 1
  Post.update_counters 5, :comment_count => -1, :action_count => 1
  # Executes the following SQL:
  # UPDATE posts
  #    SET comment_count = comment_count - 1,
  #        action_count = action_count + 1
  #  WHERE id = 5
```

Is there any easy way to do this in elixir/phoenix considering I have to update the counter of multiple columns?

Comment: Please feel free to update or give suggestion for any improvements in question asked. thanks

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags. [tag:phoenix] has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Sure @mudasobwa. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There was no need to remove [tag:phoenix-framework], though :)

Answer (score 7):

Alternativaly you can go with something like this using the `inc` option:

```
Post
|> where(id: 5)
|> Repo.update_all(inc: [comment_count: -1, action_count: 1])
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this article almost a year ago now, but it's still relevant, and as a bonus, it's written from the perspective of "coming from Rails".

https://medium.com/@lukerollans_17079/counter-caching-in-phoenix-8ac372e5c0c5

Your best bet is to use [`prepare_changes/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#prepare_changes/2) which provides a mechanism to run an arbitrary function in the same transaction. This allows you to do stuff like counter caching, or whatever you like.

It's also computed at the same time as generating your changeset, so you don't need to "specially" update counters at an arbitrary point in your codebase.